# How to think Slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm struggling a bit in Slick and i'm a recent Scala/Slick adopter. I'm used to Hibernate and/or Rails ActiveRecord but i'm having a bit difficulty joining plenty of tables.

I have the Following class pattern.

```
case class User(id: UUID, ..., profile: UserProfile)
case class UserProfile(id: UUID, ..., address: Address)
case class Address(id: UUID, ...)
```

I'm trying to have this as a Domain Model and having the Persistence Layer just fetch and join the tables to return a domain single object.

1. Is is the right way to do it in slick?
2. Is there anyway to cache the Query Results instead of being constantly querying the database?
3. Does this [Lib](https://github.com/strongtyped/active-slick/) help?
4. What's the best way of joining for example these 3 tables? 1 Query to each of them via separate DAO's or Inner Joins and use Scala's groupBy ?

Sorry if this is a "newbish" question. I'm just trying to figure out how to "Think Slick".

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no right way of doing it. It depends on what you need to do with your model... There is right way of modelling relational database model, but you already know that.
2. Slick doesn't use any caches, see [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/orm-to-slick.html#read-caching). But if you use Play Framework for example, it provides [CacheApi](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCache), but I have no experience or advice for that. But, for queries you can have some "caching", like [compiled queries](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#compiled-queries).
3. Probably yes, for simple cases, simple tables etc. But you could also use Hibernate for that, which is far more older and reliable.
4. I was stuck with it also when I was a Scala/Slick beginner, so I wrote a [blog](http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html) about that(It's on Slick's [3rd party docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/docs/third-party-slick-3) also, yes I'm bragging :p). There is also a simple companion project for it.

Understanding plain SQL, it's joins etc helps a lot when using Slick.
For example, does the outer join(left/right) order matter, and other interesting questions.

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve and i do this in all Apps i develop, i have a Domain Layer where i keep my Busines/Domain Models agnostic where i have DAO or Repo Interfaces that are implemented by the Data Access Layer that will interact with the Database

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you would simply inject a DAO into your service(Busines/Domain layer). But that is another question that doesn't regard Slick itself so much. Also, if you have Slick tables separated in files, you can use the Scala's self-type to inject a driver from DAO, which you can then simply switch (from MySQL to H2 for example), like in this PlaySlick [example](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/computer-database/app/dao/CompaniesDAO.scala).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small tutorial on play + slick some time ago. check it and see if it helps http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/

I usually have:

```
case class CaseClassA(field1, field2, caseClassB_Id)
case class CaseClassB(field3, field4)
```

but maybe there's a better approach

Comment: The thing is, i don't want to have Id's in my Domain Classes. I'm trying to do Hibernate Style

Comment: yes, but Hibernate is an ORM, while 'Slick is a modern database query and access library for Scala'.. Still if someone can suggest a better approach to referring other domain classes in a slick case class, I would be happy to know

Comment: Ok ok. Got it. 1 more thing. What's the best way to join those tables. Multiple Queries, or Join the Tables and in-memory groupBy ?